# QPainter draws text below specified rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, drawtext

I've noticed strange behavior with QPainter class usage. I had some working code, using drawText:

```
        painter.drawText(this->m_textArea,
                         Qt::AlignCenter,
                         this->m_text);
```

After refactoring of `m_text` member, `drawText` started to draw it below specified rectangle. I made some investigation and find out, that `drawText` have problems with user null termination:

```
TrainEntry::TrainEntry() :
    m_textArea(),
    m_text(TrainEntry::LENGTH + 1, QChar::Null)
{

}

void TrainEntry::setText(const char * text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TrainEntry::LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        if ('\0' == *text)
        {
            this->m_text[i] = QChar::Null;
        }
        else
        {
            this->m_text[i] = QChar(*text);
            ++text;
        }
    }
}
```

When I removed +1 size initialization and replace `QChar::Null` with `QChar(' ')`, everything is ok.

I also checked documentation and seen, that QString for strings with specified size is null-terminating itself:

> QString ensures that the character at position size() is always '\0', so that you can use the return value of data() and constData() as arguments to functions that expect '\0'-terminated strings.

I used fixed allocated QString intentionally. Maybe self null-terminating is overengineered, but in my opinion it shouldn't be considered as bug. Can anyone explain why this happens? I use Qt 4.8 version.

Comment: I would assume that Qt code which handles `QString` relies on its length member exclusively. So, if you store `QChar::Null` in a `QString` of sufficient length, it just does it (i.e. stores the `QChar::Null` as contents of string). However, you cannot expect that it has the same meaning like in C strings. Instead, it's considered in output somehow. So, you shouldn't do it but use the `QString` like intended. (Conversion to a C string with `QString::data()` is another topic.)

Comment: @Scheff all I wanted to do is to make sure, that there will be no out-of-bounds error inside drawText. But I think you are right, it might be misuse.

Comment: When converting from const char*, I’d use QString::fromUtf8(), QString::fromLatin1(), etc. Don’t iterate manually over single characters and try to manually null-terminate. That said, the setter should already take a const QString &, not a const char*.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld const char * comes from non-Qt application. I would like to avoid QString::fromXXX methods, because they create heap-allocated temporary objects.